How can I add a custom CSS class to the WooCommerce MyAccount navigation menu?
The list of navigation items used in the WooCommerce 'My Account' pages, seems to dynamically created.
<nav class="woocommerce-MyAccount-navigation" aria-label="Account pages"></nav>

But I'd like to add a custom class to the nav element, is there a specific hook for allowing this? This is what I'm trying to achieve:
<nav class="woocommerce-MyAccount-navigation sticky-top" aria-label="Account pages"></nav>

All I can find is information on how to modify the list items within the menu using  the woocommerce_account_menu_items filter

There is no hook for that, see it on myaccount/navigation.php template file.
But there are 2 ways to achieve this:
1. By overriding the template file via your child theme
Copy this file from the WooCommerce plugin to yourchildtheme/woocommerce/myaccount/navigation.php
Then you can open edit this file, make the required changes and save.
2. By using JavaScript (jQuery) like:
add_action( 'wp_footer', 'my_account_menu_custom_js' );
function my_account_menu_custom_js(){
    if ( is_account_page() ) : ?>
    <script>jQuery('.woocommerce-MyAccount-navigation').addClass('sticky-top');</script>
    <?php endif;
}

Code goes in functions.php file of your child theme (or in a plugin). Tested and work.

Option 1 of overriding the template file was the simplest way of doing this, thanks very much!
